# Does a sequence of pairwise disjoint event converge to the empy set, $\emptyset$?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(A_n)$ be any sequence of pairwise disjoint events, is

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n = \emptyset.
$$

always true?

Conceptually I would say yes, since if we partition $\Omega$ an infinite amount of times, I guess that the events would get smaller and smaller.

Comment: How are you defining limits of sets?  The concept makes little sense generally and it is usually only used for chains of the form $A_1\supseteq A_2\supseteq A_3\supseteq\dots$ or $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq A_3\subseteq\dots$.  I suppose if you were to try to define $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n = \{x~:~\exists N~(\forall n>N~x\in A_n)\}$ then yes, the result is empty.

Comment: The expression $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n$ is not well defined if the sets $A_n$ are disjoint. (as far as I know)
One usually defines such limits only for increasing or decreasing sets, i.e. sequences of sets which fulfill $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1}$ (or $\supseteq$, respectively).

Comment: The expression that @JMoravitz defined is also known as the $\liminf$ of a set-sequence and may be written as $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{m \geq n} A_m$. If the sets are pairwise disjoint it is (trivially) empty.

Comment: This isn't really a very great definition of convergence of sets however... consider applying that definition to the sequence of sets $\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\dots$... with that definition you'd have the sequence "*converges to $\{1\}$*" which might not match our intuition.  The sequence of numbers $2,3,2,3,2,3,\dots$ we would have said didn't converge.

Comment: Yes, the intuition behind the $\liminf$ is that it contains all $\omega$'s, which are contained in \textit{all but finitely many} $A_n$'s.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think of the limit of sequence of sets as when the lim sup and the lim inf are the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can say that a sequence of sets $(A_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges to $A$ if
$\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n=\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n=A$, where
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcap_{N\geqslant 1}\bigcup_{n\geqslant N}A_n
$$
and $$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcup_{N\geqslant 1}\bigcap_{n\geqslant N}A_n.
$$
One can show that $\omega$ belongs to $\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n$ if and only if the set $\{n\in\mathbb N, \omega\in A_n\}$ is infinite and that $\omega$ belongs to $\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n$ if and only if there exists an integer $N$ such that $\omega\in A_n$ for all $n\geqslant N$.

The inclusion $\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n\subset \limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n$ always hold. In the particular case where $(A_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is pairwise disjoint, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n$ is empty, because no $\omega$ belongs to more than one $A_n$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any book with this or any other proof?